# Where are my video, voice and audio settings stored in Counter Strike Source?

Tags: counter-strike-source

I have been trying to backup my config files in Counter Strike Source but I couldn't find the video, audio and voice settings. Where are they actually stored?
I am using 7launcher

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, *7launcher* is a pirated/cracked version of Counter-Strike Source, which we don't support here on Arqade. The best information I can give you as to the config files is that wherever the game is installed, there should be a path that looks similar to `counter-strike source/cstrike/cfg`. Inside `cfg` is the files you want to backup. To avoid missing any settings, I would recommend simply copying the whole folder, as it's not large enough to warrant picking and choosing specific files.